# I have a unique or distinct recors in all the column, table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need a unique record all the table and all the column how can I get

Table1
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

1. ```
      A.     P.      20.   21
   ```
2. ```
      B.     Q.     18.   19
   ```
3. ```
      C.     R       17.   16
   ```

Table2
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5

1. ```
      A.     P.      51   58
   ```
2. ```
      B.     Q.     60   65
   ```
3. ```
      C.     R       18   25
   ```
4. ```
      D.     S.      33.   31
   ```

Table3
Col1 col2 col3 col4   col5

1. ```
      A.     P.      60.    13
   ```
2. ```
      B.     Q.     75      61
   ```
3. ```
      E       t      100   108
   ```
4. ```
      F.      U.      91.   98
   ```

Output of table (I need like dz output)

Col1 col2  col3  col4  col5

1. ```
      A.     P.      20.   21
   ```
2. ```
      B.     Q.     18.   19
   ```
3. ```
      C.     R       17.   16
   ```
4. ```
      D.     S.      33.   31
   ```
5. ```
      E.     T.       100  108
   ```
6. ```
      F.     U.       91.   98
   ```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images (or links to images...) Also show us your current query attempt. [mcve].

Comment: I know that you want to solve your problem but you have to describe better your question without pieces of paper. Please provide some sample data.

Comment: please also show your attempt

Comment: As my knowledge I added my question is it ok for u all

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [T-SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the unique rows you can combine all the records from all three tables using **union all** and use **distinct** to get unique rows.

```
select distinct col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from (
select col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table1 
union all
select col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table2
union all
select col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table3 )T
```

Or if you wan to show first record of each unique col1 and col2 value as in your output table use below query (I didn't use Col1 in the query since it's serial number for that table only):

```
with cte as (
select row_number() over (partition by Col2,Col3 order by sl)rn, col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from (
    select 1 sl, col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table1 
    union all
    select 2 sl, col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table2
    union all
    select 3 sl ,col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 from Table3 )T
)select row_number() over (order by col1),Col1,Col2, Col3, Col4 from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Yes by using cte it's  works ...thank you

Comment: Thanks @Rani. It would be highly appreciated if you accept my answer by clicking the green button.

Comment: @Rani hope you are doing great. If it helped then please accept this answer by clicking the green check so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the first result based on the first two columns.  One method uses `union all`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from table2 t2 
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2)
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from table3 t3
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.col1 = t3.col1 and t1.col2 = t3.col2) and
      not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t3.col1 and t2.col2 = t3.col2) ;
```

You can also do this with `row_number()`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4k
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by which) as seqnum
      from ((select 1 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select 2 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4
             from table2
            ) union all
            (select 3 as which, col1, col2, col3, col4
             from table3
            )
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

With an index on `(col1, col2)` in each of the tables, I would expect the first version to be faster.